# Inserting a PHP page into Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, include

I know this is a fairly simple task but I think there's something I'm missing here. I want to put in a PHP page I have built from another site into my current Wordpress site, beneath the content section and above the footer. There is no coding within this section, just content. It only needs to be called upon and appear where I need it to on the page.

Some searching has lead me to believe it belongs in the page or single template before the footer. I've tried include tags and the like without any luck. Can anyone shed some light on this? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Look at one of the source pages they probably include a header and a footer file.

Comment: Can you open your `wp-content/themes/<your-theme>/footer.php` file, and insert an `include_once("/your/content-above-footer.php")` at the top?    *Note: this breaks WordPress's theming abstraction, but may get you going for now.*

Comment: As I mentioned in another suggestion's comment string, putting it in the footer did get the information to appear. All of my styles (which are referenced on a separate style sheet from WP's CSS) are now gone. How can I keep those styles intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the footer.php from your Wordpress theme and add

```
<?php include once("/path/to/your/script.php"); ?>
```

after the last

```
<php get_sidebar(''); ?>
```

include.

Comment: I never thought of putting it in the footer! That got the information to appear but the separate CSS sheet it referenced is no longer being read. When viewing the php page on it's own all of the styles are accounted for. How can I get it to keep the styles I assigned it?

Comment: Nevermind, I had a link that was no longer being referenced correctly. THANK YOU!

Comment: If it helped you, can you please select one of the answers as 'the answer'? It will help other Stackoverflow (and Google traffic) users to find their solution.

Comment: Definitely the best option if you want to include it on every page

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your wordpress theme and layout. Basically you need to include this php file in the template for the page that you want it to appear on. Generally this is the index.php file for the post page and page.php for pages. You can check which template your pages are using by going into the dashboard and editing the page (the option is on the right hand side under 'template')

If you're unsure you may want to look here for more info:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: I should mention that I am using a static frontpage with the Frontpage Template.

Answer (score 0):

if your php file located on other website/server you can use file_get_contents to get its content and display it in your page.

Go to single.php and put this code between get_sidebar() and get_footer()

```
<?php 
    $mycontent = file_get_contents('http://example.com/your-php-file.php');
    echo $mycontent;
?>
```